# R / Bookdown: specify rmd_files in render_book() function

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

We use `bookdown` very frequently to write course material at our university. We use `rmd_files:` within "_bookdown.yaml" to specify the rmd-files to be included in the book. Our bookdown projects tend to become rather long and complex, and `_bookdown.yaml`ends up looking something like this:

```
rmd_files:
- index.Rmd
- folder1/subfolder1/file1.Rmd
- folder1/subfolder1/file2.Rmd
- folder1/subfolder2/file3.Rmd
- folder2/subfolder3/file4.Rmd
...
```

Using `_bookdown.yaml` to specify the files is limiting in the following ways:

- it leads to a lot of repetition (e.g. `folder1` is repeated for each child element)
- the complex structure is implicit and obscure
- selecting only a subset of files to be rendered involves manual labour (say I just want to use all files from folder 1)

So we have moved over to depicting our file-structure in a separate yaml file and using helper functions to update `_bookdown.yaml` according to our needs. This method seems a bit clunky, and it would be much more elegant **if we could pass a vector of files to `render_book()`** instead of specifying the rmd-files in `_bookdown.yaml`. **Is that possible?**

Note: using `render_book(..., preview = TRUE)` is not a solution, we would like to re-render the book with a specific set of rmd-files.

Comment: Have you seen the [RMarkdown Cookbook](https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook) format? they put all the main chapters in the parent folder and only the css/js/images are stored in child folders. this is from rendering your directory as a `bookdown_site`

Comment: yes, many of the bookdown books follow this structure. We would like to keep our nested hierarchy. Do you know if rmd-files can be passed explicitly to `bookdown::render_book`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the new [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bookdown.html)

Here is cuts from the book[image]

This WOULD match your directory IF you pull all your .RMDs from the child folders and in the same parent directory as the `index.RMD`.

[image]

If you name the files accordingly, then your book will render in the correct order (numerically). If you do this, you will not have to name every .RMD file in the yaml. You just have to render your `index.RMD` which gets instructions from the YAML you have saved

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I think I was not clear enough in my question: I would like to be *more* explicit in specifying my rmd-files, not less explicit. Plus, I would like to keep our current file structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include any files from anywhere, using this line in your `_bookdown.yml` (NB: brackets, commas, and indent!)

```
rmd_files: [
  index.Rmd,
  folder1/subfolder1/file1.Rmd,
  folder1/subfolder1/file2.Rmd,
  folder1/subfolder2/file3.Rmd,
  older2/subfolder3/file4.Rmd
]
```